# "Insuficient Storage" when there is space available in the SD card

Tags: insufficient-memory

I have recently installed a 32 GB SD card on my Android phone. I moved all my apps to it, and they only fill 600 MB of it. I have 152MB available on my Internal storage.

With all this space available, every time I try to install a new app (even if it is really small) I get an error saying that I have to remove unused apps, along with a list of apps suggested for removal. I have already tried to clean the cache, and it didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! That's a question asked here very frequently. Have you already checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), where we've set up some first aid? What of its solutions have you tried, and how did they fail? As that wiki states, size of your external SD card is irrelevant here. That's all about "internal storage". So if those hints in the wiki don't solve your issue, please [edit] your question and include details on the overall size of your internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 500MB of free space in internal storage to install apps.

Comment: Says who? That would be valid if your internal storage is 5 GB overall. OP didn't specify how big internal storage of the device in question is.